# Modifying a WITH CTE AS statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to figure out how to modify this WITH CTE AS statement. What I have below will update my StackCustomerAltID numericly with the customers in ABC order that are not blank and Delflg = 0. But I need to figure out how to modify it to update my StackCustomerAltID numericly, customers in ABC order with the blank customers. But the problem seems to be the blanks. I tried removing the where clause but it puts the blanks first then the ones that have actual customers in them.

Existing Query

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT StackCustomerAltID,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Customer) AS RN
    FROM dbo.StackCustomer Where DelFlg = 0 and Customer <> '')
UPDATE CTE
SET StackCustomerAltID = RN;
```

without where clause

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT StackCustomerAltID,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Customer) AS RN
    FROM dbo.StackCustomer )
UPDATE CTE
SET StackCustomerAltID = RN;
```

Comment: Do you want to change the order that the numbers are assigned, with the blanks receiving the highest numbers instead of the lowest?

Comment: yes, the ones with customer names in abc order then the blank ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        StackCustomerAltID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
        (
            ORDER BY 
                CASE WHEN Customer Is Null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
                Customer
        ) AS RN
    FROM 
        dbo.StackCustomer 
)
UPDATE CTE
SET StackCustomerAltID = RN;
```

Comment: This is the right approach.  However, I think it can be done more simply with `ORDER BY Customer IS NULL, Customer`

Comment: the blank customers are actually blank not null, I assume this wouldn't work then?

Comment: @JShaffer You just need to replace `Customer Is Null` with `Customer = ''`.

Comment: @Cargo23 That syntax doesn't work for me in SQL Server 2016.

Comment: that worked with me changing it to Customer = ''